# Dealing with 'cannot be resolved to a variable' in Drools

Tags: drools

I have the following rule

```
rule fpf_mdd_music_dans_drama salience 180
when
    $reslist : List(size > 0) from collect (NvbQueryResults(control() in ("fpf_mdd_music_dans_drama_p1",
                                                                           "fpf_mdd_music_dans_drama_p2")))                                                                                
    $qr : NvbQueryResults(control()== "fpf_mdd_r94_upf")
then
    res = (NvbQueryResults)$reslist.get(0);
    insert(new NvbQueryResults("fpf_mdd_music_dans_drama",res.count() + $qr.count()));
end
```

The NvbQueryResults looks like this

```
case class NvbQueryResults(control: String, count: Int = 0)
```

my problem is that I get this error when I try to run the rule

```
Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='fpf_mdd_music_dans_drama']
res cannot be resolved to a variable
res cannot be resolved
```

I don't understand what is wrong, can someone please explain to me me the problem.

Comment: You're assigning `res` without declaring it.  `NvbQueryResults res = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right hand side of a Drools rule is regular Java. In Java you can't assign values to a variable before you declare it.

```
NvbQueryResults res = $resList.get(0);
```